# How to wrap a whole span element in a DIV?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a `div` with four `span` elements inside of it.
The last `span` lies beyond the width of the `div`, so it's word-wrapped to the second line.

I want to wrap the whole `span` (the last `span`) into the second line, not to cut off the content.

I tried to use `white-space/word-break` on the `div`, but all seems to cut the span's content at the end width of the `div`.

Anybody help me solving the issue.

Comment: can you add some code to a fiddle?  it's hard to debug code without it

Comment: Are you tying to create columns out of the span elements?

Comment: Can you please show the problem on http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: `<span>` is an "inline" element so it's supposed to behave like that.  If you want the whole thing to wrap to another line as a complete unit, use a "block-level" element, not a `span`.  Unfortunately, you're going to have to show us a concise code example if you want more exact help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys,
Yes, I create the demo in jsfiddle and found it out.
please see below:

http://jsfiddle.net/r7vs7hng/4/

```
<div style='border: #c0c0c0 1px solid; line-height: 40px; background-repeat: no-repeat;width:450px;'>
    <div class='secondmenubar'><img style='vertical-align: middle' alt='' width='25' height='25' src=''/><div style='display: inline; margin-left: 5px; vertical-align: middle'>button1</div></div>

    <div class='secondmenubar'><img style='vertical-align: middle' alt='' width='25' height='25' src=''/><div style='display: inline; margin-left: 5px; vertical-align: middle'>button2</div></div>

    <div class='secondmenubar'><img style='vertical-align: middle' alt='' width='25' height='25' src=''/><div style='display: inline; margin-left: 5px; vertical-align: middle'>button3</div></div>

    <div class='secondmenubar'><div style='display: inline; '><img style='vertical-align: middle' alt='' width='25' height='25' src=''/><div style='display: inline; margin-left: 5px; vertical-align: middle'>button4</div></div></div>

    <div class='secondmenubar'><img style='vertical-align: middle' alt='' width='25' height='25' src=''/><div style='display: inline; margin-left: 5px; vertical-align: middle'>button5</div></div>

    <div class='secondmenubar'><img style='vertical-align: middle' alt='' width='25' height='25' src=''/><div style='display: inline; margin-left: 5px; vertical-align: middle'>button6</div></div>

    <div class='secondmenubar'><span  style='display:inline-block;' title='used as kendo icon' class='k-icon k-i-close' >1234</span><div style='display: inline;'>button7</div></div>

    <div class='secondmenubar'><img style='vertical-align: middle' alt='' width='25' height='25' src=''/><div style='display: inline; margin-left: 5px; vertical-align: middle'>button8</div></div>

    </div>
```

I found 3 point:

1. The outside div need mark as inline-block, not inline;
2. if you have an inline element like  inside the div, you could mark it as dislay:inline-block;
3. if you use this span as a kendoUI BUTTON, you need to wrap an inline-block element outside of it.(That block me here)